# Using the genitive with "this week"

Tags: possessives, modifiers

Since a noun can be used as modifier of another noun (e.g. *family* in "good family house"), is it grammatically correct to use *this week* as modifier, or is only the genitive possible with *this week*?

If both are acceptable, is there any difference between *this week report*, and *this week's report*?

The reason I am asking is that in my native language, nouns are not used as modifiers; in Italian, the equivalent of *family house* is *casa familiare*, where *familiare* is an adjective. Sometimes, I get confused about whether I should use a modifier or another construct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*This week report* is not acceptable, because a [*determiner*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner) such as *this* is ordinarily taken to head the entire noun phrase which it heads, not just the element which follows it.

That is, *this week report* would be parsed as [this [week report]]: it implies that a specific [week report] is under discussion.

As far as I know *week report* is not a meaningful compound, so the mismatch is immediately apparent. But suppose the construction employed your other example, *family house*, which **is** a meaningful compound. The phrase *this family house* would be parsed as *[this [family house]], that is, "the family house I am pointing at". It cannot be parsed as [[this family] house], "the house of the family I am pointing at".

Accordingly, you require a construction which somehow isolates [this week] as a noun phrase: *this week's report* or *the report for this week*. You could in theory write *the this-week report*, introducing a new determiner; but that's not idiomatic, because it doesn't reflect a speakable construction: there are no hyphens in speech.

Answer (score 0):

As StoneyB says, there isn't a good way of using "this week" as a modifier noun, however there are options to use the adjective form of the word "week", i.e. "weekly":

> This is the weekly report from HR.
>
> We need the weekly report before Monday.
>
> I've just come from our weekly staff meeting.

Alternatively, you can always choose to use the genitive directly:

> This is this week's report.
>
> I'm going to this week's staff meeting in five minutes.